# The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini. Unable to upload a new theme in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, themes, cpanel

I am unable to upload a new theme in wordpress.The maximum limit showing right now is 10 mb. What changes should I make in CPanel. I have created a new file in Public_html named php.ini.
and pasted these lines.

```
upload_max_filesize = 256MB
post_max_size = 32M
memory_limit =  32M
max_execution_time = 300
```

Comment: which server you are using?

Comment: if you are using a shared hosting then you can not increase the limit (some hosting might provide). So I will recommend you to upload theme by FTP then activate that by admin.

Comment: can you upload it through cPanel? or have you tried that?

Comment: No I haven't tried uploading from FTP. I just know to upload from Wordpress-Appearance-Themes.

Comment: many host providers have disabled custom `php.ini` files. you can try to add this config into a `.htaccess` file if your server is apache. If it still does not work, you can use the solution proposed by urfusion or try to contact your host provider to see if they can change the config

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**1: Theme Functions File**

There are cases where we have seen that just by adding the following code in theme’s functions.php file, you can increase the upload size:

```
@ini_set( 'upload_max_size' , '64M' );
@ini_set( 'post_max_size', '64M');
@ini_set( 'max_execution_time', '300' );
```

**2. Create or Edit an existing PHP.INI file**

For this method you will need to access your WordPress site’s root folder by using FTP or File Manager app in your hosting account’s cPanel dashboard.

In most cases if you are on a shared host, then you will not see a php.ini file in your directory. If you do not see one, then create a file called php.ini and upload it in the root folder. In that file add the following code:

```
upload_max_filesize = 64M
post_max_size = 64M
max_execution_time = 300
```

This method is reported to work for many users. Remember if 64 doesn’t work, then try 10MB (sometimes that work).

**3. htaccess Method**

Some people have tried using the .htaccess method where by modifying the .htaccess file in the root directory, you can increase the maximum upload size in WordPress. Edit the .htaccess file in your WordPress site’s root folder and add the following code:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 64M
php_value post_max_size 64M
php_value max_execution_time 300
php_value max_input_time 300
```

Answer (score 1):

Using .htaccess file in wordpress. You can define below lines,

Open it .htaccess in folder and added the following into a newline at the end of the file.

```html
php_value memory_limit 256
php_value upload_max_filesize 64M
php_value post_max_size 64M
php_value max_execution_time 300
php_value max_input_time 1000
```

Save your changes and overwrite the .htaccess file.

Get More info, you can follow the link, 
For upload file size: https://www.bitcatcha.com/blog/increase-maximum-upload-file-size-in-wordpress/

For Increase Memory Limit size :https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/increase-memory-limit/

Answer (score 1):

you can create php.ini file in wp_admin folder in root wordpress directory

```
 open php.ini and override  these values 
      1- upload max size 
      2- post max size 
      3- max execution time
  now php.ini file looks like that 
         upload_max_filesize = 128M
         post_max_size = 128M
         max_execution_time = 180
```